# Is there an equivalent of the async library but for node.js's child_processes

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, parallel-processing

The popular [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library in node does a great job of handling a lot of complicated control structures for asynchronous functions in node. For example, say I have a collection of bank account ID's and I want to retrieve their balances from an API then sum the resulting balances. I could achieve this in async by doing something like this:

```
var accountIds = [0001,0002,0003,0004,0005,0006]
async.mapLimit(accountIds,
  3,
  function fetchBalance(accountID, cbk) {
    var balanceURL = "http://someapi.com/account/balance/" + accountID;
    get(balanceURL, cbk);
  },
  function end(err, balances) {
    if (err) {
      console.err(err);
    }
    console.log(sum(balances));
  }
);
```

This saves me from having to write the plumbing to keep track of how many asynchronous functions are simultaneously dispatched, ensuring that all functions are eventually completed, tracking errors, etc. Additionally, it works well in node because I/O (in the form of web requests) are the limiting factor of this program.

However, let's imagine that instead of having individual tasks that are I/O bound, we have individual tasks that are CPU bound. Async is not going to give me any true performance benefits since node.js is only going to be running a single main thread. One solution to parallelizing this kind of workload in node might be to use the [child_process](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process) library and spawn a bunch of worker processes to handle the CPU bound work. My question is, is there a library that could handle the plumbing/coordination of these workflows like async does for I/O bound, asynchronous functions? If not, would this be worth writing? I think it could be an interesting exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be possible to use async along with child_process to achieve what you want.

```
async.mapLimit(accountIds, 3, function(accountId, next) {
    child_process.execFile('myworker.js', [accountId], next);
}, function(err, results) {
    console.log('done', err, results);
});
```

I guess spawn/fork can be used as well but you would have to listen for the events instead of the callback to check if the process is done.

Obviously `myworker.js` should do some heavy computation or this will end up being slower than  just doing it in the main thread. From nodejs [documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options) `These child Nodes are still whole new instances of V8. Assume at least 30ms startup and 10mb memory for each new Node. That is, you cannot create many thousands of them.`

If you are going to use these processes frequently it might be better to create them once and send them messages to do the work to avoid the startup cost.

Comment: Cool! Good to know that at least one of the `child_process` library functions takes a callback. This seems reasonable when my arguments are going to be one or two objects. If we're talking about each process getting 10,000+ account Id's as arguments though are we going to be restricted to using messages to pass them to the child?

Comment: Yeah you would need to use some sort of IPC if you want pass around data.

Answer (score 0):

For the specific case there may be an audio conversion library built for Node.  Otherwise, you can use the lame command to convert audio, but that means the complexity of interacting with a shell command.

Generally speaking it's easy to set up an Express server exposing REST-like URL's.

`app.get('/path/:param', function(req, res, next) {
       CPUintensiveCalc(req.params.param, function(err, result) {
           res.send({ result: result});
       });
    });`

Then in another Node.js app, you could use http.request to call the service.

I wrote a longer reply here:  http://davidherron.com/blog/2014-07-03/easily-offload-your-cpu-intensive-nodejs-code-simple-express-based-rest-server

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure where you are getting audio conversion from. Also, if you're offloading your CPU-intensive node code to another server, aren't you still going to be blocking *that* server's event loop? What if you need to perform 2 CPU intensive tasks simultaneously?